# Hiding terminal output when chaining commands

Tags: command-line

From the terminal, I like launching my standard working applications ... gedit with my todo-list, firefox and chromium.

To save time, I (1) chain this command into one line, (2) silence all error messages from stderr and stdout with `2&>1 >/dev/null` and (3) background the processes with `&` to regain a clean terminal:

```
gedit ~/Desktop/todo.txt 2&>1 > /dev/null & firefox 2&>1 > /dev/null & chromium-browser 2&>1 > /dev/null &
```

It seems to work fine except for one small detail.  Gedit opens the todo file as well as a new textfile with the name 2.  Are the pipes misplaced?

Comment: The correct code is:
gedit ~/Desktop/todo.txt > /dev/null 2>&1 & firefox > /dev/null 2>&1 & chromium-browser > /dev/null 2>&1 &

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tend to see `>/dev/null 2>&1` and not `2>&1 >/dev/null`

Then `>` is probably key here since the next options for gedit is (a) filename(s).

Man page for gedit states for `filename(s)`:

> Specifies the file to open when gedit starts - if this is not specified, gedit will load a blank file with an Untitled label. **Multiple files can be loaded if they are separated by spaces**. gedit also supports handling of remote files. For example, you can pass the location of a webpage to gedit, like "http://www.gnome.org", or load a file from a FTP server, like "ftp://ftp.gnome.org/robots.txt".

If I read this correctly: the 2 is seen as a filename since a space preceeds it. That would suggest you need the `>` to tell gedit that it is not a filename that comes next.

---

I myself would create a script and have the commands on separate lines.

Comment: I chose this one as the accepted answer because it helped me see that I mistyped 2&>1 instead of 2>&1 as supplied by you.  Duh! :)

The correct code is:
gedit ~/Desktop/todo.txt > /dev/null 2>&1 & firefox > /dev/null 2>&1 & chromium-browser > /dev/null 2>&1 &

Answer (score 2):

Quick answer:

```
gedit -b wallet.pem > /dev/null 2>&1
```

The `-b` option put `gedit` in background.

Longer answer:

For a task like this one I'd put these applications in the startuo of your Desktop Environment.